# What did I do wrong in the following piece of code that caused threads to never terminate?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following piece of code which I expected to print "DONE" at the end. But when I ran, "DONE" was never printed and the JVM in fact never terminated.

What did I do wrong?

```
// File: Simple.java
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Simple {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        doTest(3);

    }

    private static void doTest(final int times) {

        ScheduledExecutorService tp = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(times);

         Thread[] runnables = new Thread[times];
         for (int i = 0; i < runnables.length; ++i) {
             runnables[i] = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
         }

         // schedule for them all to run
         for (Thread t : runnables) {
             tp.schedule(t, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         }


         try {
            tp.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("DONE!");
         }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }


    static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("hello world");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(times)` uses Executors.defaultThreadFactory() for its ThreadFactory.

[Here is the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single
>   non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named main of some
>   designated class). The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute
>   threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> - The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security    manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
> - All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception
>     that propagates beyond the run method.

So, here is what you had; but I changed 3 things.

- Added the shutdown hook
- Made the schedule delayed by an extra second for each to demo that the shutdown is being called even before some of the threads are being called to run by the scheduler.
- Lastly, you were telling it to wait forever using the Long.MAX. But I think you were doing it because the shutdown feels like it would shutdown now. But it won't.

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      doTest(3);

  }

  private static void doTest(final int times) {

      ScheduledExecutorService tp = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(times);

      Thread[] runnables = new Thread[times];
      for (int i = 0; i < runnables.length; ++i) {
          runnables[i] = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
      }

      // schedule for them all to run
      int i = 1;
      for (Thread t : runnables) {
          tp.schedule(t, i++, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }


      System.out.println("Calling shutdown");
      tp.shutdown();
  }


  static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          System.out.println("hello world");

      }

  }
  ```

Hope that answers your question. Now, you're kinda duplicating stuff.

If you are going to use the `executerservice`, you should just tell it to schedule stuff for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    doTest(3);

}

private static void doTest(final int times) {

    ScheduledExecutorService tp = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(times);

    for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
        tp.schedule(new MyRunnable(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }



    System.out.println("Calling shutdown");
    tp.shutdown();
}


static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("hello world");

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I dont understand why I should make it wait a second longer ? (I'm actually trying to get all 3 of them to run at the same time)

Comment: You don't have to. I was just trying to demonstrate that the `tp.shutdown()` doesn't stop the threads from running first.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I still find it strange that the threads won't die on their own

Comment: That's just the behavior of non-daemon threads. Ill add the javadocs to my answer.

Comment: This has nothing to do with daemon threads whatsoever. The problem was that shutdown was never called and that awaitTermination only terminates after all submitted work is finished *and* shutdown has been called.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that you're doing wrong here.

First off, if you're using an `ExecutorService`, you shouldn't then also be creating your own threads. Just submit Runnables to the executor directly - the executor service has its own collection of threads, and runs anything you submit on its own threads, so the threads you created won't even get started.

Second, if you're done with an ExecutorService, and are going to wait until it's terminated, you need to call `shutdown()` on the executor service after you submit your last job.

Comment: Isn't this an API design flaw? I would've thought the threads should die on their own and that I dont have to call `shutdown()`

Comment: If you had started the threads that you created, they would finish on their own and terminate. But you never started them. Submitting a thread to an executor service says "just treat the body of this like any Runnable", and the ExecutorService will call the Thread's run method from the service's own threads. Some method is needed on the service to say "not going to submit any more jobs" - I might have named that `close` instead of `shutdown`, but how else is the ExecutorService supposed to know that you're done submitting jobs, and it should terminate?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to [shutdown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) your `ExecutorService`:

```
tp.shutdown(); // <-- add this
tp.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Also I should mention that creating `Thread`s to use them as `Runnable`s is not only meaningless, but can be misleading as well. You should really use `Runnable` instead of `Thread` for `runnables` variable.

```
Runnable[] runnables = new Runnable[times];
```